# JavaScript to make an action on an input box

Tags: javascript, php, forms

Don't shoot me I'm new to this web programming. I'm an old (and rusty) VB programmer. I've been reading a little about js, php and html.  Basically I've never used 3 different languages in one document.

Say I create an input box the user has to enter a value in,  using html.  Obviously this box is named say 
"name First". Can I use js to grab the data in the box to preform an operation. 
My idea is that I'm creating a form, I want to be able make copy and paste easier for the user. If I can I want to use js too copy all the data to the systems clip board if they double click on the input box.  I'm using php because the form will be interacting with a database.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can get the data from an input box with Javascript.

Suppose your input field looks like this:

```
<input id="firstname" type="text">
```

Then you could get the value of that like this:

```
var firstname = document.getElementById("firstname").value;
```

---

Javascript does not have the ability to interact with the system clipboard directly for security vulnerability reasons.  There are some work-arounds using an Adobe Flash component called zeroclipboard, but these won't work if Adobe Flash is not installed.  Or, you could simulate your own clipboard (likely using local storage) that would work just on your own site.

Comment: Ok back to the drawing board on that one then. Thanks

Comment: However you can still save their input temporary into your database, and then, using PHP you can "paste" it in.